# Цитирование и восклицательный знак!

Tags: пунктуация

Предложение: *«Всегда готов!» – с гордостью отвечали советские пионеры.* Нужна запятая после кавычки перед тире?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**«Всегда готов!» — с гордостью отвечали советские пионеры.**
Запятая не требуется.

Comment: https://izamorfix.ru/rus/sint_punkt/chuzhaya_rech.html   нашла

Answer (score 1):

Считаю, что здесь нет цитирования, а есть предложение с обычной **прямой речью**, которая заканчивается восклицательным знаком. Запятая после кавычек не нужна.
Такое предложение можно оформить двумя способами.
*«Всегда готов!» — с гордостью отвечали советские пионеры.

— Всегда готов! — с гордостью отвечали советские пионеры.*

[Прямая речь перед словами автора](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=157#pp157)

"Всегда готов!" ― ответил лошадиным ржанием его напарник, но, прерванный отчего-то мстительным взглядом дружка, сомкнул рот. [Олег Павлов. Карагандинские девятины, или Повесть последних дней // «Октябрь», 2001]

— Всегда готов! — радостно откликнулся Гарик и вскинул руку в дурашливом жесте пионерского приветствия. [Александра Маринина. Не мешайте палачу (1996)]